# Can't install fail2ban on Centos 7.1

Tags: centos, fail2ban

I am trying to install fail2ban on my centos 7.1 server

I did:

```
yum install epel-release
yum install fail2ban
```

But i am getting some error messages:

```
yum install epel-release
Package epel-release-7-5.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

-----

[root@elliot ~]# yum install fail2ban
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: mirror1.34sp.com
 * base: centos.mirror.transip.nl
 * epel: ftp.nluug.nl
 * extras: centos.mirror.transip.nl
 * updates: centos.mirror.transip.nl
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package fail2ban.noarch 0:0.9.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.6 for package: fail2ban-0.9.2-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: python-inotify for package: fail2ban-0.9.2-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: gamin-python for package: fail2ban-0.9.2-1.el6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package fail2ban.noarch 0:0.9.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.6 for package: fail2ban-0.9.2-1.el6.noarch
---> Package gamin-python.x86_64 0:0.1.10-16.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: gamin = 0.1.10-16.el7 for package: gamin-python-0.1.10-16.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgamin-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: gamin-python-0.1.10-16.el7.x86_64
---> Package python-inotify.noarch 0:0.9.4-4.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package fail2ban.noarch 0:0.9.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.6 for package: fail2ban-0.9.2-1.el6.noarch
---> Package gamin.x86_64 0:0.1.10-16.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: fail2ban-0.9.2-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.6
           Installed: python-2.7.5-18.el7_1.1.x86_64 (@updates)
               python(abi) = 2.7
               python(abi) = 2.7
           Available: python-2.7.5-16.el7.x86_64 (base)
               python(abi) = 2.7
               python(abi) = 2.7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[root@elliot ~]#
```

Can someone help me to fix this problem?
I also tried to install it on a new server, and i had no problem on that server

I also can give you a fee is someone can help me out with this!

Thank you very much

P.S if you want you can login in my PC

Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Your system is confused (specifically the repositories). You appear to have both CentOS 6 and CentOS 7 repositories enabled (and possibly packages for both installed).

Specifically you appear to be attempting to install fail2ban from the EPEL 6 repository.

Check your configured repositories carefully and try `yum clean all && yum makecache && yum install fail2ban` to force yum to clean and recreate its metadata cache.

Answer (score 0):

Running:

```
yum clean all
```

Then

```
yum install fail2ban
```

Did the trick for me on Centos 7.2